# eclipse debugging (CDT) console writeline

Tags: c, eclipse, debugging, console.writeline, openocd

I'm trying to debug my stm32f0 with eclipse(CDT), gdb and openocd. Is there any way (like you do in for example visual studio) to have a var print to the console. Something like console.writeline or debug.writeline?

thanks

Comment: May be I missed something in your question... whats wrong with standard gdb way like "p printf("%d", ivar)" (consider ivar have type int) and so on?

Comment: You mabey miss the how to do so in eclipse with gdb in my question. I didn' t knew gdb had a printf. How do i use that?

Comment: gdb have no printf. It just can call any function in program you debug, that in turn may have some printf-like things inside to output on your microcontroller's console.

Answer (score 1):

Attach USB2TTL converter to the PA9 and PA10 pins and use serial port to print any debug information.

On Linux you may use `screen` to view any serial port. For example:

```
screen /dev/ttyUSB0 115200
```

Try to run my template project:

https://github.com/dobromyslov/stm32f0-chibios-template